# How to send JSON object from express server to next js page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I am new to next js and express I am trying to send post data from the server to the client which in this case is my web browser.
I am able to receive data on the server, now I want to send this data to the respective page.
Following is the code for my server.js file:-

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.use(express.json());

  server.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
    req.body.data
    res.send(req.body.data);
    console.log("Post data : ",req.body.data)
  });

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Now I would like to send req.body.data to the posts page. How do we do this using nextjs?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The json method of response can be used to send json directly.

```
res.json(req.body.data);
```

Comment: Thank you @Vishnudev much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an endpoint in your Express application that returns the data to the client via [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json)

Then access it from your React application (probably in the [getInitialProps](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle) method) by making an Ajax request to it.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin much appreciated.

Comment: Just like we can return in get can we return in post as well. I am trying to do something as follows :-   server.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
    req.body.data
    res.send(req.body.data);
    console.log("Post data : ",req.body.data)
    res.json();
    return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: "Anup" })
  }); Will this work.

Comment: @anup — No. You're trying to respond *three* times to the *same* request. You should do what I said.

Comment: @Quentin if data called by ajax, will it be still SSR? can google tracker track the data that rendered with ajax for SEO? thanks for the solution